# Deserialize mongo document property which implements Inteface base on condition

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using `Mongo database` with `C# driver` in my `ASP.Net Core` application.
For now I'm having a document `User` :

```
public class User 
{
    public Guid Id{get;set;}

    public int Role {get;set;}

    public IVendor Vendor {get;set;}
}
```

My `Vendor` in `User` class can be `FoodVendor` or `FoodDeliveryVendor` which implements the same `IVendor` interface and deserialized base on `User role`.

I have tried searching for interface deserialization in Mongo database, the only solutions I can find were about deserializing interface to a specific class which implements it.

Any solutions about deserializing `interface property` to specifc class base on specific conditions ?

Thank you.